# How to iterate da.linalg.inv over a dask array dimension

Tags: dask

What is the best way to iterate `da.linalg.inv` over a multi-dimensional dask array?

I have a dask array of shape `(4, 4, 8, 8)`, and need to compute the inverse of the last two dimensions. With numpy, `np.linalg.inv` loops over all dimensions except the last two, so in the following example, I can just call `np.linalg.inv(A)`.

I have chosen to use a `for loop`, but I have read about [gufuncs in dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-gufunc.html) (the documentation seems a little outdated). However, I'm not sure how to implement the it, particularly the `"signature"` bit,

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

A = da.random.random((4,4,8,8))
A2 = A.reshape((-1,) + A.shape[-2:])
B = [da.linalg.inv(a) for a in A2]
B2 = da.asarray(B)
B3 = B2.reshape(A.shape)

np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(
    np.linalg.inv(A.compute()),
    B3
)
```

My attempt at a gufunc leads to an error:

```py
def foo(x):
    return da.linalg.inv(x)

gufoo = da.gufunc(foo, signature="()->()", output_dtypes=float, vectorize=True)
gufoo(A2).compute() # IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to apply the numpy function `np.linalg.inv` over your Dask array rather than the dask array function.

If np.linalg.inv is already a gufunc then it might work as expected today

```
np.linalg.inv(A)
```